# High frequency inverter using irf540n

Tags: inverter, mosfet-driver, high-frequency, gate-driving, resonant-converter

I want to make a square wave inverter for DC resonant converter. I have constructed this full-wave bridge inverter which is to work at frequencies of 50kHz to 100Khz.

[image]

The input is 37V DC. The gate signal in of 5v and at a frequency of 50kHz. The problem is that the output is not coming. Only a square wave signal of 1.4V is generated with the same gate signal frequency.

[image]

I think that the MOSFETs need a gate driver but don't know how to design one for this circuit or some kind of bootstrapping circuit. I have to run this with an Arduino UNO. kindly need suggestions on what to do.

Comment: There are many posts on this site re fair drivers and inverters. You will need level society's for the high side gate and hate drivers for all gates. Look through this site and then come back and ask questions.

Comment: You have misunderstood how a MOSFET work. Look at examples of working H-bridges and compare to yours.

Comment: can you please refer a source where I can get complete information about the gate drivers and H- bridge inverters.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: Just use gate driver ICs that do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

> *The gate signal in of 5v and at a frequency of 50kHz.*

It's not going to happen with your circuit. Consider this: -

[image]

The upper MOSFETs are source followers hence they provide no voltage amplification and the source follows (clue in the name) the gate but maybe 1 or 2 or 3 volts lower. So, if the gate signal is 0 volts to 5 volts repeating, the output p-p will be a couple of volts at best.

> *I have constructed this full-wave bridge inverter which is to work at frequencies of 50kHz to 100Khz.*

Well, you may have constructed it but no, you have not designed a H bridge. There are plenty of web designs available so I suggest you find one that uses bootstrap drivers and is capable of working at your supply voltage range.